# How to handle PDF font fallback perfectly when generating it?

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdfkit

I'm currently working on a project that can convert HTML canvas to PDF, user can select the font and draw the text in the canvas and export as a PDF(vector), but there's a problem that user can enter other language text that the font doesn't really support it. It's shown fine in the canvas because the browser did the font fallback mechanism maybe to grab the system font as a fallback, but in the exported PDF it's all corrupted. I've embedded the font in the PDF but the font doesn't have corresponding glyph, and the PDF reader like adobe doesn't have font fallback mechanism so it all become `.nodef`

I have two ideas but that aren't really satisfying.

**1.** Collect all glyph from each sentence and create a new font

Walk through each char and check if current font has corresponding glyph, if so, adding it to the new font list, if not, using an alternative font from the font stack #1 as the fallback to get the glyph and adding it to the new font list, then finally converting it as a new font and embedding it in the new PDF.

It seems good but in reality the performance of generating new font is terrible.

(I was using `Opentype.js` to load and write a new font, when we exported the font by using `toArrayBuffer` method, it took 10 mins for 6,000 words)

#1, Font stack is a stack like `['Crimson Text', 'Pt Sans', 'Noto Sans']`, if the first font can't find corresponding glyph then go next until the end we give up.

**2.** If encountered any missing char, change the `font-family` of that sentence to `Arial Unicode MS` or `Noto`

It's pretty simple but it converts every word in the sentence to `Arial Unicode MS` or `Noto`, besides, it's hard to find a good font that contains most of language's glyph and we can't use font stack mechanism because we only can use one font in one sentence.

My goal is to make the exported PDF similar with the canvas that user drew, hoping someone can give me some direction , many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution would be to embed all four fonts in your stack plus noto (all suitably subsetted, preferably), and switch between them mid-word as required.

Building a new frankenfont from the fonts as you suggest is not required, though I admire the ambition!

Comment: But how do you know which language the text is? like the text `中文Englishかたかな자기 소개少量, 样品FrançaisÜÜÜ`, which font should I use? PDF only did the font fallback for English(latin words)

Comment: Well, first you would need to work out exactly the sequence of glyphs used to represent the unicode codepoint sequence in question. Then, obtain a list of which of these glyphs are in each font. Then compare the two, preferring fonts higher up your stack when a glyph is available in multiple ones. PDF text showing operators don't take unicode - they take codepoints which reference into a given font using its encoding scheme, or one expressed in the PDF font object itself. (TLDR: this stuff isn't easy. Start with Latin characters and other easy ones like Cyrillic. Asian languages are hard.)